# Rails Console Broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I discovered today that my ruby console on rails is no longer working. (I don't work out of the console all that often, so not exactly sure when or how this happened). I'd like to get feedback on whether others have encountered this issue, and whether I should reinstall ruby, rails, or any other program or configuration.

When I enter

```
$ rails console
```

It gets me to what looks like the console, but anything I enter returns a NoMethodError, with undefined methods that are typos of what I actually entered.

For example, when I entered

```
irb(main):001:0>  editor = Editor.new(name: "bob")
```

I get the response

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'oews' for main:Object
    from (irb):8
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in 'start'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in 'start'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in <top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in 'require'
    from script/rails:6:in '<main>'
```

which seems to be a misinterpretation of the "new" method. Also, the railties-3.2.6 folder referenced above seems to be empty.

This happens in both my SQlite3 and PG environments.

Any insight on what may be causing this? I want to minimize the number of reinstallments if possible.

I'm currently running ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.6

Thanks much!

Comment: What happens if you don't try to invoke methods on Rails objects? For example, what do you get with `puts 'foo'`?

Comment: @JohnFeminella: Seems the problem fixed itself(?) upon restarting everything. Sorry, had convinced myself I'd already restarted before. Hopefully this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is still not clear.

A restart seems to have fixed it. Sorry, should have done so before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are in the directory of the application. If you're on Mac or linux use the cd command.

Comment: Thanks @user1324541. Yes, I am in the correct directory. To the best of my knowledge, I am using the console correctly (as I have in the past), it is just giving me error messages with gibberish methods that it can't find. Just wondering if this is something others have encountered.